# How do I change the box colours once I hover over the boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to leave a pixelated trail once I hover over all the boxes. I've tried adding a *:hover* class in CSS my it's just changing 1 box color at once. I research a bit and found that the *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* method from *addEventListeners* works. However, I tried writing my over and over with my code without success. I've tried using the *click* method of addEventListener and it works but that's not what I want. Can anyone help me to have a look at what I should do?

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('gridColumn');

function createGrid(number) {
    makeRow(number);
    makeColumn(number);
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(row);
        row.classList.add('gridRow');
    }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
            let column = document.createElement('div');
            rows[j].appendChild(column);
            column.classList.add('gridColumn');
        }
    }
}

createGrid(16);
```

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.gridColumn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(16, 16, 44);
    margin: -2px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    gap: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM Manipulation and Events</title>
    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to you `column` created element event listener that when you will mouseover it add classList `colored`

in css `colored` class background is red

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('gridColumn');

function createGrid(number) {
  makeRow(number);
  makeColumn(number);
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.classList.add('gridRow');
  }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
      let column = document.createElement('div');
      column.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        column.classList.add("colored")
      })
      // if you want to keep changed color remove this event
      column.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        column.classList.remove("colored")
      })
      rows[j].appendChild(column);
      column.classList.add('gridColumn');
    }
  }
}

createGrid(16)
```

```css
body {
  /* display: flex;
        flex: 1; */
  height: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.gridColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgb(16, 16, 44);
  margin: -2px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  gap: 0px;
}

.colored{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('gridColumn');

function createGrid(number) {
  makeRow(number);
  makeColumn(number);
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.classList.add('gridRow');
  }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
      let column = document.createElement('div');

      column.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        column.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
      });

      rows[j].appendChild(column);
      column.classList.add('gridColumn');
    }
  }
}

createGrid(16);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.gridColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgb(16, 16, 44);
  margin: -2px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  gap: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>DOM Manipulation and Events</title>
  <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `backgroundColor` of the cell to desired color using `mouseenter` event and set it back to default using `mouseleave` event.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('gridColumn');

function createGrid(number) {
    makeRow(number);
    makeColumn(number);
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(row);
        row.classList.add('gridRow');
    }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
            let column = document.createElement('div');
            rows[j].appendChild(column);
            column.classList.add('gridColumn');
        }
    }
}

createGrid(16);

document.querySelectorAll(".gridColumn").forEach(cell=>{
  cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e)=>{
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = generateRandomRGB();
  })
  cell.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e)=>{
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  })
})

function generateRandomRGB(){
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.gridColumn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(16, 16, 44);
    margin: -2px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    gap: 0px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM Manipulation and Events</title>
    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @JabriJuhinin Please Have a look